# Boost/Voronoi - Can't create voronoi_diagram in class, can in function

Tags: c++, boost, boost-polygon

I'm trying to put this:

```
boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram<> diagram;
```

... in my class, but I get this error:

```
error C2248: 'boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram<T>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'boost::polygon::voronoi_diagram<T>'
```

If I declare it in a function body instead, I do not get this error.

Comment: Show the relevant code. Reduce your code sample until you understand it. (See also **[Nobody Writes Testcases Anymore](http://kera.name/articles/2013/10/nobody-writes-testcases-any-more/)** and **[Solve your problem by almost asking a question on Stackoverflow](http://blog.jerryorr.com/2014/04/solve-your-problem-by-almost-asking.html)**.)

Comment: Perhaps use this as a starting point http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a97aac99320b615